# _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames and Modern Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

**Question**

In developing SharePoint Framework web parts, is there any way to wait for a Modern page to load before running a piece of code?

On classic pages and in the days of Script Editor Web parts and JavaScript solutions we could simply use the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` array.

**What am I trying to do?**

I want to wait for the title banner to load on a modern page so I can ascertain its containing div's height. On a modern page the title banner may or may not have a background image, which affects the height.

**How does it work?**

It would be a bonus if someone could explain how a modern page loads. Are the different elements on the page (title, web parts) loaded asynchronously using AJAX calls?

Comment: what exactly are you waiting to get loaded ?

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to the question.

Comment: If you only needs to check that one image then try using image.onload to make sure that it's loaded.